# competing risk regressions: how does it differentiate between different outcomes in output?

Tags: r, survival

I'm trying to get my head wrapped around competing risk regressions using [this tutorial](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#So_what%E2%80%99s_the_problem), and I'm a little confused on how to specify the model correctly / how to understand the output for the model I am specifying.

Using their example. Status has 3 values 1, which is death by cause a, 3 which is death by cause b, and 2 which are the censored cases. Is the output showing how the hazard rates for 1 or 3, or some combination? And how would I set it to which one I want to use?

```
library(cmprsk)
data(Melanoma, package = "MASS")

shr_fit <- 
  crr(
    ftime = Melanoma$time,
    fstatus = Melanoma$status,
    cov1 = Melanoma[, c("sex", "age")],
    cencode = 2
    )

shr_fit

## convergence:  TRUE 
## coefficients:
##     sex     age 
## 0.58840 0.01259 
## standard errors:
## [1] 0.271800 0.009301
## two-sided p-values:
##  sex  age 
## 0.03 0.18
```